# About the norm of sum/difference of orthogonal projection operators

Tags: functional-analysis, projection

In our functional analysis homework, we are asked to consider the norm sum/difference of two orthogonal projections $P_1, P_2$. For convenience, I am considering $P_1, P_2$ as orthogonal projections onto $M,N$ finite dimensional subspaces. This question is not difficult if we further assume $M,N$ are orthogonal to each other: let $\{\phi_n\},\{\psi_n\}_n$ be orthonormal bases for $M,N$ respectively. One can extend the union of these two collections to an orthonormal basis $\{\varphi_n\}$ of the Hilbert space $H$. Hence, we can write
$$
P_1 \pm P_2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k (\cdot, \varphi_k)\varphi_k.
$$
Then one not only knows the norm of $P_1 \pm P_2$, but also knows even the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

My question is: can we derive a more general statement if $M,N$ are not orthogonal to each other? I even got a bit stuck when I think about $M,N$ are just one-dimensional subspaces. Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: Instead of getting stuck, go on and analyze a specific (easy) setting on the plane.

Comment: @Berci Thank you very much for your hint! In the planar setting, I do get a lower bound for the norm of, for example, $P_1 - P_2$: say $x,y$ are distinct, non-parallel vectors, and let $M,N$ be corresponding subspaces generated by them. Then I computed that given $z$ with norm $1$, $\|P_1z - P_2z\|^2 = 1 - |(x,y)|^2$. I suspect that this has to be the norm of the operator $P_1 - P_2$, as in the extreme case when $(x,y) = 0$, it is known that $\|P_1 - P_2\| = 1$. Could you provide some more hints regarding how to look at the upper bound of the norm? Thank you very much!

Comment: By the triangle inequality $\|P_1\pm P_2\|\le 2$.